# Can you access Siri search querys from an app that runs in the background?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

Lets say I install a app on my phone which runs in the background, now every time I open Siri and start with the word "BOX" as a example "box whatever" it will open a specfic website (like www.box.com) and use the words after box as a specific search query something like (www.box.com/search/whatever).

Essentially can a iOS app add functionality to Siri to redirect specific commands to the app which then builds a URL (or whatever it needs to do)?

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

Siri has very specific Human Interface Guidelines. In order to follow such guidelines, your app can only do the following:

[image: Siri human interface guidelines]

These are provided by Apple. More human interface guidelines with Siri can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/features/siri/) and you can learn more about using Siri with apps [here](https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/).